# Can css3 'not' selector exclude a number of seletors?

Tags: css, selector

here are the codes:

html:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="notme">
    <div>notme!
        <div>notme!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div:not(.notme){
    background: #f00;
}
div:not(.notme *) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

The result is 'div:not(.notme *)' doesn't work.

So the question is: css 'not' selector can exclude a div and all its child nodes? or is there other better solution?

Comment: No reliably - why not set the default `div` color, then the color for `.notme`?

Comment: It works. But where is problem?

Comment: Or why don't you use: `div.notme div {}` What is the sense of `div:not(.notme *)`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka my project is very special, I must use a global selector(like div{background:#f00}) to effect all div, but some div and its child nodes don't need to be effected

Comment: this is why I sad, you can set the exceptions `div.notme * {background: #fff}`

Comment: @lolka_bolka no, the div and its child nodes need to keep their original background color...

Answer (score 1):

You can override the styling applied to your `div` elements by applying different styling to elements with the class `.notme`:

```css
div {
    background: #f00;
}

div.notme,
div.notme div {
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="notme">
    <div>notme!
        <div>notme!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am afraid that this solution is not suitable for me, please see the comments above.

Comment: @HOT.CHO can you not then add a class to the `div` elements you want styled instead?